# How to disable the page refresh due to activeTabChange of TabContainer inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, tabcontainer

I am using AJAX TabContainer control with following settings. When I change a tab the postback happens and whole page refreshes. Because AutoPostBack="true"> .  To AJAxify the behavior, I added UpdatePanel around it but still the page is refreshing. The control need to go to server because user controls contains some grids which need to be populated.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTLTop" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <AjaxCT:TabContainer ID="tcProducts" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Style="height: 100%;
                vertical-align: top; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" OnActiveTabChanged="Products_OnActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <AjaxCT:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="MBS" ID="pnlMBS">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:ucA ID="ucA1" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </AjaxCT:TabPanel>
                <AjaxCT:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="ABS" ID="TabPanel1">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc2:ucB ID="ucB1" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </AjaxCT:TabPanel>
            </AjaxCT:TabContainer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How can I disable the page refresh and at the same time server side operation happens in this case?

Please advise. Thanks
AJ

Comment: I copy an paste your example to test and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ChildrenAsTriggers="True" on your update panel.  Though, I personally do not see how your code does not work as is.